# Same selectors click add and remove

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I like to get different content in the same place one at a time.
So when the user clicks "Select me 1" it opens Lorem ipsum 1 and if he clicks "Select me 3" the code will remove the display block from the Content1Box.

Here is my DOM and [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vjandrei/g1rta3n2/)

```
<div id="contentContainer">
<div class="box" id="content1box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 1</p>
</div>
<div class="box" id="content2box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 2</p>
</div>
<div class="box" id="content3box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum 3</p>
</div>
</div>

<div id="contentSelection">
<div class="contentSelect" id="content1">
    <p>Select me 1</p>
</div>
<div class="contentSelect" id="content2">
    <p>Select me 2</p>
</div>
<div class="contentSelect" id="content3">
    <p>Select me 3</p>
</div>
</div>
```

```
$('#contentSelection .contentSelect').on('click',function(){
TweenMax.to(("#"+ $(this).attr('id') + "box"), 0.5, {display: "block", delay:0.5}); });
```

I am using TweenMax for the animation this one.

Comment: How exactly do you animate the `display` style ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just hide all `.box` elements prior to the animation:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/aptrav32/)

```
$('#contentSelection .contentSelect').on('click', function () {
    $('#contentContainer .box').hide();
    TweenMax.to(("#" + $(this).attr('id') + "box"), 0.5, { display: "block", delay: 0.5 });
});
```